# Angular2 validations and displaying errors in view

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular

I am using Angular2 and Java for standalone back-end in my web project.

I have validation handling in back-end. If I press, for example - save button,  http call occurs to back-end (where my data is validated), and returns response as json which contains validation error metadata (or empty).

Now I want to show those errors to my angular2 view (for email and name). How can I do that?

```
        @Component({
selector: 'my-selector',
templateUrl: `
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <input  id="name" [(ngModel)]="name" />
  <div>space for error message</div>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input  id="email"  [(ngModel)]="email" />
 <div >space for error message</div>
  <button (click)="onSave()"> Save </button>`  })

      export class EmailForm { 
        private name:string;
        private email:string;
        private errorMessages
    public onSave() {
        return this._deService.add(.....);
    }}
  //and I have validationErrorMessages for that input,recived from back-end,let already deserialized form
     let messages: ErrorMeta[] = [
     { validatorKey:'required', message:'Required',controlId:'name'},
     { validatorKey: 'invalidEmailAddress',message:  'Invalid email address',controlId:'email'}
     ];
```

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html. You can use async validators to call to the server.

Comment: Dear Gunter,in my project I dont use forms.
I recivie errors (http call already implemented  and i recive errors ) as json and must show on view. 
So,I have @ messages and want to show those messages on screen.And set invaid state.?
Maybe it is not possible,and I must use forms.

But I have on question about using FormBuilder.
This would work fine but what if our form grows with more controls?

Comment: Sure you can do it but this way the question is just too broad. Your question should show the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed. How does the data look like that you get back from the server. How should we know **how you actually want them shown**.

Comment: I edited the question,please review it.And one question about  using FormBuilder. This would work fine but what if our form grows with more controls?

Comment: Formbuilder should work fine with larger forms.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

```
getErrors(controlId) {
  return this.messages.filter(err => err.controlId == controlId);
}
```

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input  id="name" [(ngModel)]="name" [class.invalid]="getErrors('name').length"/>

<div *ngFor="let err in getErrors('name')">
  {{err.validatorKey}} - {{err.message}}
</div>

<div>space for error message</div>
<label for="email">Email</label>

<div *ngFor="let err in getErrors('email')">
  {{err.validatorKey}} - {{err.message}}
</div>

<input  id="email"  [(ngModel)]="email" />
<div >space for error message</div>

<div *ngFor="let err in getErrors('email')">
  {{err.validatorKey}} - {{err.message}}
</div>

<button (click)="onSave()"> Save </button>
```

Comment: No,each message must be under its control.
And I think that,it would be better,set invalid state of something,maybe to Controls?

Comment: Ok,and how set invalid state for controls?

Comment: I updated my answer (only for the first input, same for the others)

Comment: Nice,can I resolve that in back-end,not touching to control?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: [class.invalid]="getErrors('name').length" you are put in <input> component.
I dont want change my <input>.
Can I ,for example   create control ,and corresponding control's validation state change in that control's class.

Comment: Seems there is some code missing. Please wrap code in backticks `

Comment: **[class.invalid]="getErrors('name').length"**  you are put in <input> component. I dont want to change my <input>. for example- Can I  create new control by `<div *ngFor="let err in getErrors('name')">
  {{err.validatorKey}} - {{err.message}}
</div>
`,and change  corresponding control's(in my case input control) validation state in new control's class.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create new control".

Comment: sorry. I mean new component with  `<div *ngFor="let err in getErrors('name')"> {{err.validatorKey}} - {{err.message}} </div>` template.And opportunity to toggle valid/invalid state corresponding(maybe passed) component.(in my case `<input>`)